# Scrolling issue when keyboard open in center widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a appbar and bottom bar and there is Bottom widget to register. And there is top widget to show icon. My center part has login view and it should be in centre according to design. Issue is I want to keep bottom register button below keyboard when it opens. I tried using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to true. in this case it is not scrolling and when it is false so it shows below register button above keybord.

And login form has column widget.

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        if (AppConfig.showLogo)
          Container(
            child: AppConfig.logo,
          ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 90,
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: Dimens.d20.responsive(),
                    vertical: Dimens.d10.responsive()),
                child: BlocConsumer<AuthNewBloc, AuthNewState>(
                  listenWhen: (prev, next) =>
                      prev.notification != next.notification,
                  listener: (context, state) {},
                  buildWhen: (prev, next) =>
                      prev.status != next.status ||
                      prev.isBusy != next.isBusy,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return state.status.when(
                      initial: () => const Text('Initial'),
                      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      loadFailed: (_) => const Text('Failed'),
                      loadSuccess: (_) => LoginForm(
                        userType: _userType!,
                        showForgotPassword: true,
                        onLogin: _login,
                        onNavigate: _navigate,
                        countryList: state.countryCodes,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (AppConfig.allowRegister)
          Expanded(
              flex: 13,
              child: RegisterButton(
                userType: _userType!,
              ))
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Want to hide `didn't have account` below keyboard and login form always be in center of the screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> To ensure that the register button stays below the keyboard when it opens, you can use a combination of resizeToAvoidBottomInset and SingleChildScrollView. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, // Set to true to resize the body to avoid the keyboard
    body: Column(
      children: [
        if (AppConfig.showLogo)
          Container(
            child: AppConfig.logo,
          ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 90,
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: Dimens.d20.responsive(),
                    vertical: Dimens.d10.responsive()),
                child: BlocConsumer<AuthNewBloc, AuthNewState>(
                  listenWhen: (prev, next) =>
                      prev.notification != next.notification,
                  listener: (context, state) {},
                  buildWhen: (prev, next) =>
                      prev.status != next.status ||
                      prev.isBusy != next.isBusy,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return state.status.when(
                      initial: () => const Text('Initial'),
                      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      loadFailed: (_) => const Text('Failed'),
                      loadSuccess: (_) => LoginForm(
                        userType: _userType!,
                        showForgotPassword: true,
                        onLogin: _login,
                        onNavigate: _navigate,
                        countryList: state.countryCodes,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (AppConfig.allowRegister)
          RegisterButton(
            userType: _userType!,
          ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

> With `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to `true`, the `SingleChildScrollView` inside your `Center` widget should allow the content to scroll when the keyboard opens, ensuring that the register button remains visible and accessible below the keyboard.